# How to loop over enum without values on TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, enums

I have the

```js
enum EthereumNetwork {
  MAIN_NET,
  ROPSTEN,
  KOVAN
}

class EthereumHDWallet {
  constructor(network: EthereumNetwork) { }
}
```

The task is to write a test which goes over all possible networks and trying to create EthereumHDWallet. Something like that:

```js
  for (const network in EthereumNetwork) {
      const wallet = new EthereumHDWallet(network);
      it('constructor', () => {
        expect(wallet).toBeDefined();
      });
  }
```

Unfortunately, the code above doesn't work because of error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EthereumNetwork'.
Does anyone know way around?

Comment: It's important to point out that `enum`s in TypeScript boil down to _both_ the numeric index _and_ the string representation. That's what you're seeing in the examples you've provided.

Comment: turned out, the example I've provided doesn't actually work either.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over *all* the keys will give you too much (it will also give you the keys `"0", "1", "2"`).  You can filter it down *and* get the type-safety you want, but you have to tell TypeScript that this is safe (with the `as K[]` in `enumKeys` below):

```
function enumKeys<O extends object, K extends keyof O = keyof O>(obj: O): K[] {
  return Object.keys(obj).filter(k => Number.isNaN(+k)) as K[];
}

for (const networkName of enumKeys(EthereumNetwork)) {
  const network = EthereumNetwork[networkName];
  const wallet = new EthereumHDWallet(network);
}
```

Comment: this is excellent! Is there any reason why TypeScript shouldn't treat operators "for in" and "for of" in a similar way out of the box for enums?

Comment: `for ... of` they could (because the generated `enum` could implement the `iterator` protocol), but they can't change `for ... in` behavior with enums without more runtime emit (which is counter to the design goals of the language)